# R- how subset lines of data based on column values in a data frame

Tags: r, plot, extract, subset

I would like to plot things like (where C is column):
C4 vs C2 for all similar C1 and
C1 vs C4 for all similar C2
The data frame in question is:

```
    C1          C2  C3  C4
1   2012-12-28  0   NA  10773
2   2012-12-28  5   NA  34112
3   2012-12-28  10  NA  30901
4   2012-12-28  0   NA  12421
5   2012-12-30  0   NA  3925
6   2012-12-30  5   NA  17436
7   2012-12-30  10  NA  13717
8   2012-12-30  15  NA  36708
9   2012-12-30  20  NA  28408
10  2012-12-30  NA  NA  2880
11  2013-01-02  0   -13.89  9972
12  2013-01-02  5   -13.89  10576
13  2013-01-02  10  -13.89  33280
14  2013-01-02  15  -13.89  28667
15  2013-01-02  20  -13.89  21104
16  2013-01-02  25  -13.89  24771
17  2013-01-02  NA  NA  22
18  2013-01-05  0   -3.80   20727
19  2013-01-05  5   -3.80   2033
20  2013-01-05  10  -3.80   16045
21  2013-01-05  15  -3.80   12074
22  2013-01-05  20  -3.80   10095
23  2013-01-05  NA  NA  32693
24  2013-01-08  0   -1.70   19579
25  2013-01-08  5   -1.70   20200
26  2013-01-08  10  -1.70   12263
27  2013-01-08  15  -1.70   28797
28  2013-01-08  20  -1.70   23963
29  2013-01-11  0   -2.30   26525
30  2013-01-11  5   -2.30   21472
31  2013-01-11  10  -2.30   9633
32  2013-01-11  15  -2.30   27849
33  2013-01-11  20  -2.30   23950
34  2013-01-17  0   1.40    16271
35  2013-01-17  5   1.40    18581
36  2013-01-19  0   0.10    5910
37  2013-01-19  5   0.10    16890
38  2013-01-19  10  0.10    13078
39  2013-01-19  NA  NA  55
40  2013-01-23  0   -9.20   15048
41  2013-01-23  6   -9.20   20792
42  2013-01-26  0   NA  21649
43  2013-01-26  6   NA  24655
44  2013-01-29  0   0.10    9100
45  2013-01-29  5   0.10    27514
46  2013-01-29  10  0.10    19392
47  2013-01-29  15  0.10    21720
48  2013-01-29  NA  0.10    112
49  2013-02-11  0   0.40    13619
50  2013-02-11  5   0.40    2748
51  2013-02-11  10  0.40    1290
52  2013-02-11  15  0.40    762
53  2013-02-11  20  0.40    1125
54  2013-02-11  25  0.40    1709
55  2013-02-11  30  0.40    29459
56  2013-02-11  35  0.40    106474
57  2013-02-13  0   1.30    3355
58  2013-02-13  5   1.30    970
59  2013-02-13  10  1.30    2240
60  2013-02-13  15  1.30    35871
61  2013-02-18  0   -0.60   8564
62  2013-02-20  0   -1.20   12399
63  2013-02-26  0   0.30    2985
64  2013-02-26  5   0.30    9891
65  2013-03-01  0   0.90    5221
66  2013-03-01  5   0.90    9736
67  2013-03-05  0   0.60    3192
68  2013-03-05  5   0.60    4243
69  2013-03-09  0   0.10    45138
70  2013-03-09  5   0.10    55534
71  2013-03-12  0   1.40    7278
72  2013-03-12  NA  NA  45
73  2013-03-15  0   0.30    2447
74  2013-03-15  5   0.30    2690
75  2013-03-18  0   -2.30   3008
76  2013-03-22  0   -0.90   11411
77  2013-03-22  5   -0.90   NA
78  2013-03-22  10  -0.90   17675
79  2013-03-22  NA  NA  47
80  2013-03-25  0   1.20    9802
81  2013-03-25  5   1.20    15790
```

There are other posts here about time series subseting and merging/matching/pasting subseting, but I think I miss the point when I'm trying to follow those instructions.

The end goal is to have a plot of `C1` vs `C4` for every `C2 = 0` `C2 = 5` and so on. Same thing for `C4` vs `C2` for every same `C1`. I know there are some duplicate C1 and C2, but the C4 for those values can be averaged. I can figure these plots out, I just need to know how to subset the data in this way. Perhaps creating a new `data.frame()` with these subsets could be the easiest?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy to plot subsets using `ggplot2`. First you need to reshape your data from "wide" to "long" format, creating a new categorical variable with possible values `C4` and `C5`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Starting with the data you posted in a data frame called "dat":

# Convert C2 to date format
dat$C2 = as.Date(dat$C2)

# Reshape data to long format
dat.m = melt(dat, id.var=c("C1","C2","C3"))

# Plot values of C4 and C5 vs. C2 with separate lines for each level of C3
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=C2, y=value, group=C3, colour=as.factor(C3))) +
   geom_line() + geom_point() +
   facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free_y")
```

The `C4` lines are the same for every level of `C3`, so they all overlap each other.

[image]

You can also have a separate panel for each level of `C3`:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=C2, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ C3, scales="free_y") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90)) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Here's a base graphics method to getting separate plots. I'm using your new column names below:

```
# Use lapply to create a separate plot for each level of C2
lapply(na.omit(unique(dat$C2)), function(x) { 

  # The next line of code removes NA values so that there will be a line through 
  # every point. You can remove this line if you don't care whether all points 
  # are connected or not.
  dat = dat[complete.cases(dat[,c("C1","C2","C4")]),]

  # Create a plot of C4 vs. C1 for the current value of C2       
  plot(dat$C1[dat$C2==x], dat$C4[dat$C2==x],
       type="o", pch=16, 
       xlab=paste0("C2=",x), ylab="C4")
})
```

Comment: Thanks eipi10. I am having difficulty implementing your solution. I have edited my data to reflect that C1 is actually just the index. So it's not as simple as copy/paste, and I am having trouble following anyway. In addition, I would like to be able to manipulate each plot independently, so the way I envision it, a native R (R base package?) solution would probably fit better (plus it might be easier for me to understand!). Thanks

Comment: I don't use `C1` at all in my solution so it shouldn't have any bearing on your results. Can you be more specific about what problem you're having?

Comment: Sure! I like to understand each step in my code and I am having trouble understanding yours. melt(), aes() are new functions to me. Otherwise, I do seem to see a `C1` in your solution and trying to switch that to reflect exactly what I need didn't go so well. The dat.m data.frame also took my `C4` and made two columns of variable "C4" all the way down and the value one column over. Hope this helps. Maybe it will fit as I've edited the original post

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused, because you've changed your column names. Are you referring to the original column names or the new ones. It would have been better (and much easier for those trying to help you) to stick with your original column names and just delete (original) column `C1`. I included `C1` in the `id.var` of the `melt` command so that it would remain as an identifier for each row, but it has no effect on the ggplot code.

Comment: Sorry eipi10. I could of gone about that a bit better. The plot I get when I use your code is very convoluted, which I am trying in order to simplify the visual. I looked into the subset() function a bit, but I can't seem to figure it out either. Any thoughts there? Simplicity may be the best solution here

Comment: I've added a base graphics method of getting separate plots for each subset. Let me know if that works.